# Can Spring VelocityViewResolver handle multiple content types?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I'm using Spring's `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` along with `VelocityViewResolver` in a REST Spring MVC application which will support many different response types.

I would like Velocity to be able to handle multiple content types, but it seems like it only supports 1 (default text/html or supplied via the contentType property).  In the config example below, I would like Velocity to support the html, csv, and custom content types.

Is this possible with 1 VelocityViewResolver? or do I need to configure one for each content type?

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/> <!-- MarshallingView -->
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/> <!-- MappingJacksonJsonView -->

            <!-- Would like the 3 content types below handled by Velocity -->
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            <entry key="csv" value="application/csv"/>
            <entry key="custom" value="application/custom"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
                <property name="cache" value="false"/>
                <property name="prefix" value=""/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `html` is handled correctly by your VelocityViewResolver, but what happens when the ViewResolver determines that the content type is `csv` or `custom`?

Comment: It returns an HTTP 406 (not acceptable) because none of the defined views accept `csv` or `custom`